# AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING IV - Decryption from Java to NodeJs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, node-crypto

I am trying to decrypt in NodeJs. It is working in Java. But I am not able to achieve same in Node.

I am using node-version: 8.4

Please find my NodeJs code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function decryption (message, key) {
    var messageArray = Buffer.from(message, 'base64');
    // var kekbuf =  Buffer(key, 'utf8');

    var ivBuffer = new Buffer([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    var iv = ivBuffer.slice(0, 16);

    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    var dec = decipher.update(messageArray, 'base64');

    dec += decipher.final();
    return dec.toString();
}
```

Please find working Java code

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

class Test1 {
  public String decrypt(String message, String key) throws Exception {
    DatatypeConverter dtc = null;
    byte[] messagArray = dtc.parseBase64Binary(message);
    byte[] keyArray = dtc.parseBase64Binary(key);

    byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyArray, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(messagArray));
  }
}
```

I am getting a different decrypted text. I am not able to achieve the same result in NodeJs as I had in Java.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Why are you not enabling padding when you are clearly using padding in the Java code?

Comment: I am getting Error after enabling it

crypto.js:181
  var ret = this._handle.final();
                         ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv.final (crypto.js:181:26)

Answer (score 0):

use crypto2 library, this library fixed the iv issue:

```
    const crypto2 = require('crypto2'); 

    AESDecrypt: function (encrypted, secretKey) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (encrypted && secretKey) {
                    crypto2.decrypt.aes256cbc(encrypted, secretKey, (err, decrypted) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve(decrypted);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    reject('Crypt - Invalid params!');
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but after trying your example, I am getting Error: (node:17805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: IV must be a buffer
(node:17805) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I just passed encryptedText and key as parameters to your function. (after npm install crypto2)

Comment: @ChaitanyaJoshi, I forgot mention the version, try to download/install crypto2 version 0.3.2, my sample code run on this version. latest version has a litle changes that will catch the error.

Comment: Thanks, but For version "crypto2": "0.3.2", I am getting an error. 
Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length

Comment: at Decipher._flush (crypto.js:156:28)
    at Decipher.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:137:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at Decipher.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at prefinish (_stream_writable.js:590:14)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:598:5)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:609:3)
    at Decipher.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:560:5)
    at processStream (/Users/******/node_modules/crypto2/lib/crypto2.js:83:10)
    at Function.aes256cbcDecrypt [as aes256cbc] (/Users/****/node_modules/crypto2/lib/crypto2.js:95:3)

Comment: CryptoJS use CBC as the default mode, and Pkcs7 as the default padding scheme. @ChaitanyaJoshi, pls try changing your java encryption to PKCS7 padding

Comment: @ChaitanyaJoshi in other way, you can try encrypt/decrypt in ECB mode, not using iv.

Comment: I cannot change Java-encryption code. I have to find some workaround in the Node.